# How to make abs() give correct result for negative numbers?

Tags: python, drivers

I am trying to use the simple absolute function abs() in Expression frame for a driver, but it won't work. I've tried to put it in long sentences, or even just typing abs(-1) but the negative still negative.I have the latest update of Blender 2.8 Beta.

I don't know why I am facing such a problem.

[image]

Comment: Weird issue... As a workaround, you can use "sqrt(pow(var,2))"

Comment: Thank you. "sqrt(pow(var,2))" works perfectly fine.

Comment: Use `fabs`  (absolute float)  Most methods from `math` module are in driver namespace.