# How do I make a driver alway move forward even if the source moves backwards?

Tags: drivers

How do I make a "driver" that works like this?

If I move object1 +X forward, then object 2 +X going forward, but if I move object1 -X backwards, also object2 +X going forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the answer from [How to make abs() give correct result for negative numbers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131857/how-to-make-abs-give-correct-result-for-negative-numbers)
you can see when using absolute (abs) in the expression, you get a positive movement when object 1 goes to the negative.

[image]

[image]